# Processing MEDIA BUTTONS on android

Tags: android

I am trying to process media button presses in my application but nothing I try seems to work. Here is my broadcast receiver:

```
private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            if (intent.getAction().equalsIgnoreCase("android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON")) {
                Log.d("EVENT", "Media button pressed");
                startStop();
            }
        }
    };
```

I registerd it in the onCreate method:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar); 

    am = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);        
    am.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(new ComponentName(getPackageName(), RemoteControlReceiver.class.getName()));     
}
```

I also tried other ways of doing it, like creating a separate BroadcastReceiver class and registering it via AndroidManifest...

EDIT: I went back to "separate class for receiver" way of doing it and now the damn thing works too well... let me explain; here is my brand new BroadcastReceiver class:

```
public class RemoteControlReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent) intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
            Log.d("EVENT", "Key code: "+event.getKeyCode());
            if ((KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK == event.getKeyCode()) && (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)) {
                Log.d("EVENT", "Received media button press");
                if (MainActivity.timer.getStarted())
                    MainActivity.timer.stopTimer();
                else
                    MainActivity.timer.startTimer();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

registerd it in manifest with this:

```
<receiver android:name=".RemoteControlReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

and this comes out in log:

```
11-23 01:47:02.848 16956-16956/com.example.andrej.ssvcounter D/EVENT: Key code: 79
11-23 01:47:02.848 16956-16956/com.example.andrej.ssvcounter D/EVENT: Received media button press
11-23 01:47:02.873 16956-16956/com.example.andrej.ssvcounter D/EVENT: Key code: 79
11-23 01:47:04.931 16956-16956/com.example.andrej.ssvcounter D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

and then the whole thing crashes. For some reason two intents get sent and i tried to filter one out with ACTION_DOWN condition but it did not help...

Comment: Receivers for the Media Buttons need to be registered with  `AudioManager`. Registering it as a regular Receiver won't work. Check [this page](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/training/managing-audio/volume-playback.html#PlaybackControls) for an example, but please note that there are a few typos in the code in that section.

Comment: Hey, thank you for your reply... I just edited my top question (and updated onCreate method) please check out the new problem that came up...

Comment: You're trying to directly access members of MainActivity from your Receiver. That's never a good idea. One possible solution is to use [`LocalBroadcastManager`](http://developer.android.com/intl/es/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to broadcast an Intent to your Activity with the data you need attached as extras; for example, a simple boolean value to indicate whether to start or stop the timer.

Comment: I fixed my code with LocalBroadcastManager ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8875292/4621584)) the way you suggested, but the crashes persisted and i found them to be occurring for an unrelated problem somewhere else. The code seems to be working consistently now. Thank you for your time!